# has no exported member 'Headers' and RequestOptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ionic4

https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-http-post/

I am following this tutorial.I am getting following errors when running ionic serve

```
ng] ERROR in src/app/home/home.page.ts:2:22 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'Headers'.
[ng] 2 import { HttpClient, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/common/http';
[ng]                        ~~~~~~~
[ng] src/app/home/home.page.ts:2:31 - error TS2305: Module '"../../../node_modules/@angular/common/http"' has no exported member 'RequestOptions'.
[ng] 2 import { HttpClient, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/common/http';
[ng]                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ng] src/app/home/home.page.ts:28:11 - error TS2339: Property 'http' does not exist on type 'HomePage'.
[ng] 28      this.http.post("http://localhost/android/Api.php?apicall=signup", postData, requestOptions)
[ng]              ~~~~
[ng]
```

Answer (score 2):

You imported it from the wrong package. Plus, `Headers` got renamed to `HttpHeaders`.

Try the following:

```
import { RequestOptions } from 'http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Also, you don't necessarily need `RequestOptions`. You can also just pass the `HttpHeaders` directly like this:

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = req.headers;

if (this.authService.checkAuth()) {
    const token = 'something';
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
}

const authReq = req.clone({ headers });
```

I also see that `this.http` does not exist, so you need to inject that into your `constructor()` like this:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
```

In your case you can send your request like this:

```
this.http.post("http://localhost/android/Api.php?apicall=signup", postData, { headers });
```

where `{ headers }` is your `RequestOptions` object, and is shorthand for `{ headers: headers }`

(You don't need to define key AND value if they're the same)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi @dave0688 i am getting error as req is not defined.I am very much new to angular.Hope you will help me

Comment: This was just a code example from my project. Will edit it accordingly.